# linked list nodes not being displayed

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

void insertnode(node* conductor)
{
    node* t;
    t = new node;
    conductor->next = t;
    conductor = conductor->next;
    conductor->next = 0;
    cin >> conductor->data;
}

int main()
{
    node *root, *conductor;
    root = new node;
    root->next = 0;
    cin >> root->data;
    conductor = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        insertnode(conductor);
    }
    conductor = root;

    while (conductor->next != 0) {
        cout << conductor->data;
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
    cout << " " << conductor->data << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

This program should display all nodes i.e.  root and i=0 to 1=3(<4), but its displaying only the root node and last entered node.
What's wrong in my code? I want to display all nodes from root node 
to the last node.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `insertnode()` Should probably insert at the end. Not always insert at the child of the root.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the for loop as the following.

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    insertnode(conductor);
    conductor = conductor->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have only 2 nodes in your list. Others are missed in memory. You have to add conductor=conductor->next; in your for loop, because "conductor" pointer changes in insertloop function are available only inside this function. In main() it stays the same as before calling this function.